# Single page mod rewriting for SEO

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo

I have a page as follows.

```
www.mysite.com/about.php
```

I want this to be set in the htaccess file so that it looks like below.

```
www.mysite.com/my-keyword-here
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?my-keyword-here$ /about.php [L]
```

So now if you enter `http://www.mysite.com/my-keyword-here` in your browser's URL address bar, you will be returned the content of `/about.php`.